# Get total number of pages in iTextsharp PDF C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using iTextSharp for pdf generating purpose . I want to get page no with total page show on footer.
my code is-

```
public class footer : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
    {
        PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
        footerTbl.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width;
      
       Chunk myFooter = new Chunk("Page " + (doc.PageNumber) + " of " + doc.PageCount, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, 8, grey))
       
        PdfPCell footer = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myFooter));
        footer.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        footer.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        footerTbl.AddCell(footer);
      
        footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (doc.BottomMargin + 10), writer.DirectContent);

    }
```

doc.PageCount is give an error

Answer (score 0):

you need to extent ITextEvents class that extends PdfPageEventHelper to add footer. in following way.

```
public class footer : PdfPageEventHelper
    {

        // This is the contentbyte object of the writer
        PdfContentByte cb;

        // we will put the final number of pages in a template
        PdfTemplate  footerTemplate;

        // this is the BaseFont we are going to use for the header / footer
        BaseFont bf = null;

        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            try
            {
                bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                cb = writer.DirectContent;              
                footerTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                //handle exception here
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
            {
                //handle exception here
            }
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

            iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontNormal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

            iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontBig = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);

            Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Sample Header Here", baseFontNormal);

            //Create PdfTable object
            PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(3);

            //We will have to create separate cells to include image logo and 2 separate strings
            //Row 1
            PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell();
            PdfPCell pdfCell2 = new PdfPCell(p1Header);
            PdfPCell pdfCell3 = new PdfPCell();
            String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";

            //Add paging to footer
            {
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(document.PageSize.GetRight(180), document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
                cb.ShowText(text);
                cb.EndText();
                float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 12);
                cb.AddTemplate(footerTemplate, document.PageSize.GetRight(180) + len, document.PageSize.GetBottom(30));
            }
          

            pdfTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 80f;
            pdfTab.WidthPercentage = 70;

        }

        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

            footerTemplate.BeginText();
            footerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
            footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
            footerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString());
            footerTemplate.EndText();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. cb.BeginText();

Comment: you need to use complete code as mentioned above because cb is initialized in  OnOpenDocument function . and in your create pdf function use this:-  PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            pdfWriter.PageEvent = new footer();

Comment: if you not used OnOpenDocument in your code then cb will not initialize and it will throw object refrence not set error.